# AzureML- access the notebook running after closing the browser

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently running a notebook on Azure ML for a neural network that is going to take a few hours to train. I accidentally exited the window. When I open the notebook again, it isn't showing any progress, but the compute instance is still saying that it's running, and the kernel is busy- the CPU and RAM usage are the same as when the model was training too. I would just like to see the progress in the model training, but have no idea how to access it.

Any ideas?- Note, I'm new to AzureML so it might be really simple and I just can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is an existing issue in AzureML, I have personally raised this using the feedback tool. I suggest doing the same, hoping the more people report this, they should prioritize it.

In the meantime, I suggest you using `sys.stdout`, to output everything to a log file, which you can have a look later on:

```html
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout

log_file = open("message.log","w")

sys.stdout = log_file

print "this will be written to message.log"

sys.stdout = old_stdout

log_file.close()
```